# How can I add more div classes to this jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a div generator that randomly places a random div in a random location within the body. So far the jquery script I am using is only generating one class of div. How can I call multiple classes? I want it to be able to randomly choose from the list of divs from my css.

Many thanks.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
makeDiv();

function makeDiv() {
    var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
    var divsize = 5;
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
    $newdiv = $("<div class='exploding' + 'box'></div>").css({
        'left': posx + 'px',
            'top': posy + 'px'
    });
    $newdiv.appendTo('body').delay(200).fadeIn(100, function () {
        //$(this).remove();
        makeDiv();
    });
}
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JaromandaX I've tried   but it only generates the exploding class div.  $newdiv = $("<div class='exploding' 'box'></div>").css({
        'left': posx + 'px',
            'top': posy + 'px'
    });

Comment: @JaromandaX  unfortunately that still only generates the "exploding" class div.

Comment: Please explain your question better ... even after creating code that creates exactly what you want (based on a comment in an answer) you then state you want something else ... so, decide what your expected output is, show what your expected output is **in the question, not in a comment** and then you may get an answer - but not from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var classes = ['exploding', 'box', 'test', 'class4', 'class5'],
      counter = 0;
      
  makeDiv();
 

  function makeDiv() {
      var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
      var divsize = 5;
      var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
      var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
      $newdiv = $("<div class='" + classes[counter] + "'>New div</div>").css({
          'left': posx + 'px',
          'top': posy + 'px'
      });
      $newdiv.appendTo('body').delay(200).fadeIn(100, function () {
          //$(this).remove();
          makeDiv();
      });
      
      counter = counter < divsize -1 ? counter + 1 : 0;
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should keep space between classes. Moreover, you can add many more as you want.

> class='exploding box anotherclass'

```
$newdiv = $("<div class='exploding box'></div>").css({
    'left': posx + 'px',
        'top': posy + 'px'
});
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. It still only seems to call the "exploding" div class.

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry if I am not clear with my descriptions. I am pretty new to jquery. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @JaromandaX It is currently generating <<div class="exploding boxes test" style="left: x px; top: x px;"></div>. What I am trying to get at is  (<div class="exploding" style="left: x px; top: x px;"></div>' '(<div class="boxes" style="left: x px; top: x px;"></div>) (<div class="test" style="left: x px; top: x px;"></div>)

Comment: @maxoium659, Have a look at the snippet now. Added class dynamically from some predefined classes ['exploding', 'box', 'test', 'class4', 'class5'].

Comment: Your new snippet was exactly what I was trying to explain. So I just had to add var class. Many thanks.